# Can scheduled (cron) Jenkins jobs access previous job status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Below is a simplified case.
I have one node named **comp01**. And I have a Jenkins job named **Compatibility**.

**Compatibility** is scheduled as follows:

```
0 12 * * 1 %IntegrationNode=Software_1
0 17 * * 1 %IntegrationNode=Software_2
0 22 * * 1 %IntegrationNode=Software_3
0 2 * * 2 %IntegrationNode=Software_4
0 7 * * 2 %IntegrationNode=Software_5
```

The jobs start as scheduled. But sometimes, because of some verification failure, the previous job takes more than expected time. So, the next job starts before the completion of the previous job.

Is there a way available in Jenkins, in which the next scheduled job stays in a queue until previous job is complete? Or can we schedule based on previous job status?

- We have tried limiting executors for this job, but when more than a couple of jobs are queued, then the expected behavior is not observed.
- We have also tried by creating resource-groups and adding multiple nodes to it, but still, expected behavior is not observed when multiple jobs are in queue.

**EDIT-1:**
We can't use `options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }` since we start the job concurrently on different nodes. Here we are struggling to ensure that when a job is started on a node, then the other scheduled jobs for the same node should wait till the current job completes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the below [option](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options)?

```
options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }
```

---

**Update**

AFAIK there is no OOB solution for your problem. But you can definitely implement something. Without seeing your actual Pipelines I can't give a concrete answer. But here ae some options.

**Option 01**

Use [Lockable Resources](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/) and create a resource per Jenkins IntegrationNode and acquire it when running the Job, the next build will wait until the lock is released.

```
lock(resource: 'IntegrationNode1', skipIfLocked: false) {
    echo "Run your logic"  
}
```

**Option 02**
You can implement a waiting logic to check the status of the previous Build. Here is an sample Pipeline and possible Groovy code you can leverage.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                        echo "Waiting"
                        def jobName = "JobA"
                        def buildNum = "92"
                        waitUntil { !isPending(jobName, buildNum) }

                        echo "Actual Run"
                    }
                   
               }
            }

        }
}

def isPending(def JobName, def buildNumber) {
    def buildA = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(JobName).getBuild(buildNumber)
    return buildA.isInProgress()
}
```

Comment: Hello @ycr, we can't use this option. I've edited my question to state the reason why. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I will try the options that you provided. Thanks